# How do I use variables for a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, file, variables

I am pretty new to PHP and am trying to use variables in a string, here is my code:

```
<?php
    $userName = $_GET['Username'];
    $message = $_GET['Message'];

    if($_POST['Submit']){ 
        $open = fopen("new.txt",'a'); 
        $text = "\n________________________________________"+$userName+":"+$message+"\n________________________________________";
        fwrite($open, $text); 
        fclose($open); 
        echo "File updated.<br />";  
        echo "File:<br />"; 
        $file = file("new.txt"); 
        foreach($file as $text) { 
            echo $text."<br />"; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Also, would I use 'a' for adding to a file? If not what would I use? Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use `.` instead of `+` for concatenation.

Or, you can just do:

```
$text = "\n________________________________________$userName:$message\n________________________________________";
```

or (to be slightly clearer to the parser):

```
$text = "\n________________________________________{$userName}:{$message}\n________________________________________";
```

Comment: Personally, I don't like variables put into strings and I always recommend using the explicit syntax of `"____" . $var . "____"` as things like code highlighting work...

Comment: Sometimes it looks a lot nicer to put them in the string. Matter of preference.

Comment: @cassy: with a PHP-aware syntax highlighting editor, variables inside strings stick out like a sore thumb. Personally I prefer embedding to having to wasting visual space with uncessary quotes/concatenation operators.

Answer (score 2):

I always like single quotes (when possible) cause they are faster:

```
$str = '5+5='.(5+5);
```

Also comma for echo instead of concatenation cause is faster:

```
echo '5+5=',(5+5);
```

And in very complex strings (if don't care for speed) and also quotes needed I use variables to make things look more clear:

```
 $dbq="\"";
 $sq='\'';
 echo $dbq,'This is in double quotes.',$dbq,'<br>';
 echo $sq,'This is in single quotes.',$sq;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$text = "\n___$userName:$message\n"` will work. Also `$text = "whatever{$var}bar{$var2}"`. The documentation for fopen is available [here](http://www.php.net/fopen) and says of 'a':

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file.

'a' in this context generally means 'append'.

Comment: Take a look at the [markdown help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for formatting guidance. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "\n________________________________________".$userName.":".$message."\n________________________________________";
```

Use `.` for concatination

`a` would append to a file, so u want to replace the content you would use `w`